How can you do a find and replace on the contents of an email in sieve?
I am trying to do a find and replace on email contents in sieve. An example of what I mean by this is if an email contained the following contents in its body,

Today, we should have abc for dinner.

could it be changed to

Today, we should have xyz for dinner.

Trying to find any guides or documentation on this topic results in absolutely nata.

It should be in the Body Extension (RFC-5173. Or, onther link to this document: RFC 5173 – Body; allows a script to test the body of a message, not just its header.

but that's just for searching, and not for replacing.....

It is recommended to avoid using filters or rules that modify the body of emails as much as possible. Such processing can disable electronic signatures like DKIM or S/MIME, and even seemingly simple text bodies may require MIME reconstruction. (Consider the case of replacing to multibyte characters for email parts specified as ASCII.)
